# Return success message after execvp?

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system, sh

I am writing a shell program, and I want it to print a success message after the execvp call before it waits for the next command. For example, if the user inputs "ls", the program will output the list of files, AND a "success" message.

Where do I put the printf("success\n")? Is there a way to return a successful call?

Here is my code:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  execvp(args[0], args);
} else {
  wait();
}
```

Comment: Put it after the `wait()` in the parent, assuming the child's exit status as returned by `wait()` is successful.

Comment: If `execvp()` succeeds, the process is replaced; no further code from the current process will be executed.  If `execvp()` fails (which simply means "if it returns" — there's no need to test its return value), then you need to report the failure and exit (well, you need to exit so that you don't have two shell processes both thinking they are in charge.  Always put error processing after any of the `exec*()` family of functions.

Comment: The parent process cannot reliably tell whether the child executed successfully until it collects the corpse of the child — unless… For example, unless it tries something like sending the child a signal number 0 (which is used to test whether a signal can be sent to the child, with possible failures such as EPERM or ESRCH).  Note that you could get EPERM even if the child is running if the child process is running a setuid program not setuid to the current user.  Note that by the time the parent tries to test for the child, the child may have exited successfully, completing its activity.